# matlab coding for 3*3 sliding window to remove noise from digital image

Tags: matlab

our project deals with removal of random valued impulse noise from a 256*256 digital image
using medium filtering.The window has to slide through the entire image.each 3*3 window is sorted and the median is calculated.then the middle element is replaced with the pixel.we are fiding difficulty in sliding it.plz help us out..

Comment: 'sliding window' usually refers to linear filter, while median filter is not a linear filter. You have to explain in more detail what is your question, and what did you try so far.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Details of the median filter are in e.g. "Digital Image Processing" by Gonzalez and Woods.  What particular aspect are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Itamar Katz: "sliding window" can also mean that you apply the filter to every pixel (and its surrounding region) in the image, as opposed to splitting the image into filter-sized blocks. In that sense, you can apply both linear and non-linear filters.

Answer (score 5):

To perform a median filter with a 3-by-3 sliding window, you can use [MEDFILT2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/medfilt2.html) like so:

```
filteredImage = medfilt2(yourImage,[3 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the function nlfilter, it is an easy way to do what you need.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/nlfilter.html

For the future, please do a bit of research and try to do something yourself before asking here.